# Два значения в char?

Tags: c#

Вкратце я делаю шахматы в консоли, мне нужно что бы `char` имел два значения, а точнее мог быть как белого цвета так и чёрного, зависит от выбора что занести в `{0}`, символ любой.

Мне нужно знать возможно ли это реализовать вообще, хоть как-то, мои знания в C# на уровне новичка, так что может я просто не понимаю или не вижу способ реализации.

```
class Char
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char One = 'П';
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", One);
    }
}
```

---

Реализовал уже всё кроме некоторых движений фигур, получилось как-то так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть один хороший char, имеющий два значения. Называется boolean. )

Comment: Да но boolean не даст мне символ, к сожалению..

Comment: @SDst, ну это ж смотря как просить

Comment: Если исходный набор символов ограничен, то наверняка не весь `char` занят, а скорее всего только первые 127 символов, ну а если шахматы, то и подавно меньше. Старший бит, например, можно занять под цвет. Тогда числа до 127 будут чёрными, а от 128 до 255 - белыми. Это один из нескольких вариантов.

Comment: @Grundy, Думаю если попросить у boolean определённый символ, да ещё и определённого цвета, точно не даст.

Comment: @Zealint Не плохая идея, но мне нужно использовать так же одни и те же символы, символизировать пешку как "П" только разные цвет давать, скорее то что я прошу можно уже назвать как целый метод в котором можно будет и назначить цвет и назначить букву, вот только в string я не могу занести метод.

Comment: Вам стоит добавить больше конкретики в вопрос: `char` - это тип, переменные этого типа могут принимать весьма широкий диапазон значений. Кроме того, вы создаете еще и _свой_ `Char`. Что мешает в свой класс добавить поле хранящее значение, которое надо выводить и поле хранящее цвет? Кроме того: если хотелось менять цвет которые будет отображать консоль - одной строчкой не обойтись. Цвет должен устанавливаться для каждого вывода отдельно.

Comment: @Grundy, Какие мы критики, я уже давно решил проблему, просто было интересно может быть можно реализовать ещё как нибудь.

Comment: @SDst, тогда вы, конечно, можете предоставить свое решение, чтобы было понятно какую именно проблему вы решали на самом деле ;-)

Comment: @Grundy, Вставил метод по меж строк, уже в котором определил цвет и переменную. Не совсем то что я хотел, но может быть можно как-то это было реализовать как я спросил, если нет так нет, мне просто нужно было знать.

Comment: @SDst, моя идея подходит даже тогда, когда нужно использовать один и тот же символ. Этого можно добиться с помощью битовых масок, которые обнуляют старший бит. Нужно сравнивать не два символа, а их результаты `&` с битовой маской между собой.

Comment: @Zealint, Я поэтому и написал что новичок, честно, ни чего не понял.

Comment: @SDst, по вашему объяснению тоже ничего непонятно, добавьте в вопрос код вашего решения

Comment: не понял за что поставили минус, вопрос вполне хороший, автор видимо только учится и хочет разобраться. Закрывать точно не стоит.

Comment: я делал SetCursorColor(цвет). И позицию курсора. Потом аппендил символ

Answer (score 9):

Самое время вспомнить, что C# - объектно-ориентированный язык и добавить пару собственных типов для описания фигур на поле.

Для начала зададим цвета фигур перечислением

```
enum FigureColor { White, Black }
```

Теперь определим фигуру. Так как фигура не может менять цвет во время игры - сделаем свойство отвечающее за цвет доступным только для чтения.

```
public class ChessFigure
{
    //буквенное обозначение
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    //цвет фигуры 
    public FigureColor Color { get; private set; }
    //конструктор
    public ChessFigure(FigureColor color, char letter)
    {
        Color = color;
        Letter = letter;
    }
}
```

Теперь создание и вывод фигуры в консоль можно сделать так

```
ChessFigure one = new ChessFigure(FigureColor.Black, 'П');

if(one.Color == FigureColor.Black) Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;  
if(one.Color == FigureColor.White) Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;   
Console.Write(one.Letter);
Console.ResetColor();
```

Это только идея, которую можно и нужно развивать дальше. Похожий прием можно использовать для клеток шахматной доски.

Старайтесь сразу отделять логику программы от ее визуализации, это поможет избежать сложностей с добавлением новых функций и изменением уже имеющихся.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, Вам нужно что-то вроде этого. Думаю, легко адаптируете к своей задаче.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    const bool BLACK = true;
    const bool WHITE = false;

    public static void display(char c, bool bw)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = bw ? ConsoleColor.Black : ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.BackgroundColor = bw ? ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Write(c);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string line1 = "RNBQKBRN";
        const string line2 = "pppppppp";
        const string line3 = "        ";

        string[] lines = { line1, line2, line3, line3, line3, line3, line2, line1 };

        bool first = WHITE;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            bool bw = first;
            first = !first;

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                display(lines[i][j], bw);
                bw = !bw;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так.

```
class Char
{
    static bool Ones;
    static string Enter;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Enter = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (Enter)
        {
            case "White": Ones = true; break;
            case "Red": Ones = false; break;
            default: Main(); break;
        }

        Console.Write("┆ ");
        if (Ones == true) White();
        if (Ones == false) Black();
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write(" ┆");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void White()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("П");
    }
    static void Black()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("П");
    }
}
```